# Does Angular JS support Object Logging

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to use Angular JS with MVC 5.0. And i want to log the complete class Object into database while doing operation Insert/Edit/Delete for this class Object.

Does angular JS provide us with any kind of library which we can use to serialize the class object and save it into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [log provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log)

```
 angular.module('logExample', [])
      .controller('LogController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
        $scope.$log = $log;
        myObject= {
         prop:1,
         prop2:2
      }
       $scope.$log.debug(myobject);

      }]);
```

Comment: how will you use it log the values in data base ?
Guess you read the question in hurry :)

Comment: I think user3560308 wanted to explain, what he want to log object before saving in db, but explained not correct , but I think I'm understood him :))

Comment: Narek Mamikonyan! could you please give some more descriptive example for this. As i am really a new one for Angular JS.

Comment: you want to log your JavaScript Object before sending it to db , am I right ?

Comment: Narek Mamikonyan! Like i have an employee object, it is set with the form values and now i am going to save those values into database, but before values are saved in the database i want to save the object state into database (serialized form). Does angular JS come with some library which i can use to save the object in serialized state automatically in the database. You can say like a Logger (elmah).. but as Elmah is for exception logging, i want to log the C# class objects while they are set.

Comment: yes angular has something like this you can check it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

Answer (score 2):

angular is a front end framework, and your database is a backend. You would need to send your object to a backend service to persist it. Angular will serialize objects to JSON for transfer using the $http service.